# Keep CSS3 Multicolumn Width Static

Tags: css, width, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a layout that would most easily be described as a horizontally scrolling pinterest.

As in, I have items that would stack up against the previous one, and instead of extending top to bottom, it goes left to right.

So far it looks like the CSS3 multicolumn property is exactly what I want. Only problem I have is that the width is flexible (despite declaring column-width). Different browser windows render different sized columns.

Currently use:

```
.multicol {
    -webkit-column-width: 150px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Example of my problem (resize window to see width change): http://jsfiddle.net/pbg3r/4/

Is there a way to keep the width fixed? I just want columns of Xpx width, and as more are added, the page is extended horizontally as needed.

The w3 spec says the only way to keep it fixed is for "all length values (in horizontal text these are: ‘width’, ‘column-width’, ‘column-gap’, and ‘column-rule-width’) must be specified."

Though I'm not sure how to give the container a set width and keep the ability to continuously expend horizontally. And even when I do, it still doesn't guarantee the set width.

Any way to guarantee a width of Xpx for each column?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer to your issue with different browsers rendering different sized columns is a simple one.

For your `.multicol` css styles you already set the styles for `webkit` browsers just like above. Since `-webkit`(which is a browser prefix) only works with `webkit` browsers, you will need to add each browser prefix to the same style in order for it to display corretly on the other browsers.

This is what you should make your style sheet look like: *(you can get rid of the spaces between each browser style if you want)*

```
.multicol {

/*webkit*/
-webkit-column-width: 150px;
-webkit-column-gap: 0;

/*moz*/
-moz-column-width: 150px;
-moz-column-gap: 0;

/*opera*/
-o-column-width: 150px;
-o-column-gap: 0;

height: 400px;
width: auto;
}
```

and here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbg3r/5/) that displays your content correctly when viewing on `webkit`,`firefox`, or `opera` browser (you can add styles for Internet Explorer just use: `-ms-`)

You also need to add browser prefixes to any other styles you have set up in your stylesheet.

Comment: I just noticed this answer. But the lack of vendor prefixes in my question was for briefness. It isn't the cause of different widths. The WC3 spec actually says, even when given a specific width, it remains flexible. I was wondering if there was a way to override it. Still haven't found a solution.

Comment: What do you mean it remains flexible? Do you want each column to stay a certain width and not resize?

Comment: Correct. No resizing. I want to define the width and have all columns conform to that width, regardless of container width (which currently is not the default behavior)